# Определение позиции объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток! Есть объект который умеет прыгать, соответственно его координата по Y изменяется. Как отследить изменение? Что бы можно было совершить какое-либо действие, когда объект прошел определенное расстояние.

Comment: Изучайте основы юнити. `Transform.position` координаты объекта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 transform.position

 GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Your_Tag_Here").transform.position;

 GameObject.Find("Your_Name_Here").transform.position;
```

Так же рекомендую ознакомиться со следующими главами документации к юнити:

[GameObject.Find](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html)

[Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)

[Tags](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html)

Comment: Добавил эту строку "GameObject.Find("Your_Name_Here").transform.position;" Выдает следующую ошибку: Assets/scripts/ScriptsPlus/right.cs(37,71): error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
Как мне совершить какое-либо действие когда объект по Y переместится например на 1 единицу выше текущего положения? Спасибо.

Comment: @anarbus создайте отдельный вопрос и приложите ваш код и текст ошибки.